# SSH to a created EC2 instance through NodeJS implementation

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My code looks like below: -

```
  AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-1' });
  var ec2 = new AWS.EC2();

  // Create the EC2 instance
  ec2.describeInstances(function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    } else {
      res.status(201).json(data);
    }
  });
```

The above code creates the EC2 instance perfectly. Now, my requirement is that I want to "**ssh to the created instance**" from my NodeJS code programatically. What step should I follow to achieve this. BTW, the whole idea is, once I could ssh to the EC2 instance programatically, the next step I will do is to install Docker and other softwares in that created Instance programatically

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As long as you have all the necessary information to be able to connect to and authenticate with your EC2 instance via SSH, you could use a module like [`ssh2`](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2) to connect programmatically to execute commands, transfer files, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm a little late for this question but I also had this problem a few months ago and it really took me a few days to find a solution.

The solution is :

`ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i "ec2-instance-key.pem" ec2-user@PUBLIC_DNS sh ./shellScript.sh`

This line of code connects to the EC2 instance and executes a shell script. You can either run a single shell script which has all the commands you want to execute or execute them via the ssh command.
You'll need the authentication key for the instance , as you can see in the command.

Hope this helps someone someday !